# Does a non-empty resolvent set imply denseness of domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A:D(A)\rightarrow X$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $X$. Let $0\in\rho(A)$, resolvent set $\rho(A)$. Then $A$ is boundedly invertible (i.e. $A$ is closed and $A^{-1}$ is bounded), which implies that it is surjective. Does this imply that $A$ is densely defined, i.e. $\overline{D(A)}=X$?

Comment: Why does $A$ being surjective imply that $A$ is boundedly invertible?

Comment: Sorry, wrong argument order.